# Setting foreground window with Windows scheduled task

Tags: winapi, window, windows-task-scheduler, setforegroundwindow

I build a fullscreen GUI application for Windows (using LabVIEW but the language should not matter much) that should start with Windows.
I want it to be fullscreen (hiding the Windows taskbar), so I set the window bounds to the screen's resolution.

When I manually launch the exe from explorer, the window hides correctly the taskbar.
But when I launch it from a scheduled task at Windows logon, it is behind the taskbar, until I click on the application. Same thing when I run the scheduled task manuallay in the task scheduler.

I tried the Win32 API function SetForegroundWindow but without success. Maybe the conditions are not met but I do not understand why, there is no other visible window.

How could I force the fullscreen of the app when it auto-starts?

If this is impossible from the application itself, an external solution to the application's code might be ok (e.g. some script running with the scheduled task), but I don't see one either.

Comment: Only the foreground application can call SetForegroundWindow

Comment: So can I set my application to be the foreground application?

Comment: No, only the foreground application can set other applications to be the foreground application.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to replicate, what the system can already do for you. You probably want to [set up a kiosk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/setup-kiosk-digital-signage).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble when I scheduled a full screen application to run at login.

The way I got around this was by creating a mouse click macro and scheduling it at user login with the app (had to set a 10-second delay to allow for the app to load).

It's a bit dodgy, but it got it done for me.